# Modify style for gist template in Jekyll

Tags: css, jekyll, gist

I am using the `{% gist xyz %}` template in my Jekyll generated site but right before the gist on the generated html page, it inserts a link to [a stylesheet on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/assets/embed-8f95cc15c5dcf1117ab18c08ff316641.css) which clashes horribly in colour with a dark themed website. I can't put the style that I want in a stylesheet in `<head>` for the obvious reason that it will just be overwritten by the inline style. After site generation, this is the relevant section of code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gist.github.com/assets/embed-8f95cc15c5dcf1117ab18c08ff316641.css">
<div id="gistNUMBER" class="gist">
  ...
```

Does anyone have an advice on how I would go about restyling the gist or disabling the addition of this stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

If you mark all of the CSS rules with `!important`, then they won't be over written. Should have thought of this sooner :P